# XmlSerializer.Serialize ambiguous

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have create testing application that has 3 classes

- Car
- Radio
- SportCar : Car (has a Radio)

As the serialize process when I create instance of XmlSerializer object I use 2 object to testing

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SportCar));
```

and

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(
    typeof(SportCar), 
    new Type[] { typeof(Car), typeof(Radio) });
```

The result of this 2 approach is identical, so I want to know what is the difference between these 2 constructor or critical point that need to use #2 constructor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The big difference is when you need to tell `XmlSerializer` about *sub* classes - for example:

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car),
     new Type[] { typeof(SportCar), typeof(Radio) });
```

Here, without the extra info if wouldn't have known (just from `Car`) about either `SportCar` or `Radio` - so if you give it a object that is actually a `SportCar`, it would fail:

```
Car car = new SportCar {...};
xmlSerializer.Serialize(destination, car);
```

You can also do this by setting `[XmlInclude(typeof(SportCar))]` against the `Car` type definition:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(SportCar))]
public class Car {...}
```

This is easier, but is only possible if the `Car` type is in an assembly that knows about `SportCar`. But you often *do* know this, so `XmlInclude` is the preferred option.

Additionally: there are some efficiency benefits of `XmlInclude`; behind the scenes the system uses dynamic type generation to make `XmlSerializer` efficient. For this reason, you should generally keep hold of (and re-use) the `XmlSerializer` instance you create; for example, by storing it in a static field. However, the system does this automatically for the default usage (`new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car))`) - i.e. no matter how many times you use this constructor, it only generates the dynamic code once. If you use the more complex constructor (`new XmlSerializer(typeof(Car),new Type[] { typeof(SportCar), typeof(Radio) })`) it will do the type generation each time.

Comment: What is the difference in the output if I specify the sub class info? (I'm new to Serialize process)

Comment: There is no difference in output between using the XmlInclude approach and the constructor (new Type[]) approach; they are equivalent. If you do neither, and ask for a XmlSerializer(typeof(Car)), but give it a SportCar - it will throw an exception.

Comment: I see, after reading topic about XmlSerializer on C# 3.0 in a nutshell and back to read your answer that mention about "about sub classes" it make me understand how XmlSerializer work. (I purchase another book to study on C#, too bad.)